How do I apply text stored in a variable to be value labels for a factor?
I have several thousand respondent occupation codes (mimicked in df below).
I also have the written descriptions of those specific occupations that come from the government of Canada's categorization of occupations (mimimicked in gov_df as below).
Notice that the number of rows in df is longer than in gov_df; it's because there are several thousand respondents, with repeating jobs (e.g. many people are teachers), but there is only one job code for teachers in the government data base.
How do I take gov_df$description and apply it as a value label to df$job_code so that I can use it as a factor if necessary?
#Data frame of respondents with job codes
job_code <- sample(seq(1000, 9000, by=10), replace=TRUE, size=10000)
job_code
df <- data.frame(job_code)

# List of job codes from government
gov_job_codes <- unique(df$job_code)

library(stringi)
descriptions <- stri_rand_strings(length(gov_job_codes), length=5, 
                                  pattern = "[A-Za-z0-9]")
df_gov <- data.frame(gov_job_codes, descriptions)
df_gov


combined_df <- merge(df, df_gov, 
                     by.x = 'job_code', by.y = 'gov_job_codes', all.x = TRUE) |>
  data.frame()


With dplyr
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  left_join(df_gov, by = join_by(job_code == gov_job_codes))


OK, I can do that. But how do I get the df_gov$descriptions attached as value labels to the factor df$job_code.
